# Writing for loop in R over imputations

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, foreach, tidy

I basically have the same sequence of code that I want to repeat for a list of numbers from 1 through 10. In Stata, I would do `foreach num in numlist 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 {` and this would be straightforward. But in R, I'm not quite sure how to execute it.

So this code...

```
d1 <- read_dta("C:/Users/Folder/imputation_1.dta")

d1$race <- factor(d1$race)
d1$educ <- factor(d1$educ)

psm_1 <- weightit(trtmnt ~ race + education + gender,
                 data = d1,
                 method = "psm",
                 estimand = "ATT")

d1$psm_weights <- psm_1$weights

write_dta(d1, "C:/Users/Folder/weighted_1.dta")
```

...I just want to repeat that while replacing the "1" with a "2", and then a "3", and so on. I could just repeat the same code and do that manually (like below) but there must be a way to loop through efficiently.

```
d2 <- read_dta("C:/Users/Folder/imputation_2.dta")

d2$race <- factor(d2$race)
d2$educ <- factor(d2$educ)

psm_2 <- weightit(trtmnt ~ race + education + gender,
                 data = d2,
                 method = "psm",
                 estimand = "ATT")

d2$psm_weights <- psm_2$weights

write_dta(d2, "C:/Users/Folder/weighted_2.dta")
```

I tried following this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.html but it doesn't seem to be exactly what I need (or I just don't fully understand it).

Answer (score 1):

This is an suggestion and i sequence as 1,2,3:

```
d=list()
psm=list()
for (i in 1:3)
{
  d[[i]] <- read_dta(paste0("C://Users//Folder//imputation_",i,
".dta"))

  d[[i]]$race <- factor(d[[i]]$race)
  d[[i]]$educ <- factor(d[[i]]$educ)

  psm[[i]] <- weightit(trtmnt ~ race + education + gender,
                 data = d[[i]],
                 method = "psm",
                 estimand = "ATT")

  d[[i]]$psm_weights <- psm[[i]]$weights

  write_dta(d[[i]], paste0("C://Users//Folder//weighted_",i,".dta"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion--the one thing that doesn't seem to work is the write_dta part. I get an error that "File path" does not exist. I added a trailing ) as well, which I think your code is missing, but still get that error regardless...?

Comment: Nevermind, I had the actual file path name wrong! Although for write_dta, I still get an error: "object 'd' not found". Perhaps it's not recognizing the [[i]] there for some reason?

Comment: It could be like this : read.csv(paste0("C://kimman//clubsimdata//Churn_",i,".csv"))

Comment: I revised the code by adding d=list()

Comment: That seems like it worked! Not sure I understand fully the d=list() and psm=list() aspects but I can learn!

Comment: In the example, we need to define an empty list i.e. d=list() before we can assign something to the list.